# Salvar id auto_increment de uma tabela em outra tabela no mesmo arquivo

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, id

Quero que o valor de **ID** gerado automaticamente em auto_increment na tabela **wpne_posts** seja salvo em uma outra tabela chamada **wpne_postmeta**

O código de INSERT da primeira ação é:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM wpne_posts");
    $sql1 = "
    INSERT INTO
      `wpne_posts`(
        `ID`,
        `post_author`,
        `post_date`,
        `post_date_gmt`,
        `post_content`,
        `post_title`,
        `post_excerpt`,
        `post_status`,
        `comment_status`,
        `ping_status`,
        `post_password`,
        `post_name`,
        `to_ping`,
        `pinged`,
        `post_modified`,
        `post_modified_gmt`,
        `post_content_filtered`,
        `post_parent`,
        `guid`,
        `menu_order`,
        `post_type`,
        `post_mime_type`,
        `comment_count`
      )
    VALUES
      (
        ID,
        '$_post_author',
        '$_post_date',
        '$_post_date_gmt',
        '$_post_content',
        '$_post_title',
        '$_post_excerpt',
        '$_post_status',
        '$_comment_status',
        '$_ping_status',
        '$_post_password',
        '$_post_name',
        '$_to_ping',
        '$_pinged',
        '$_post_modified',
        '$_post_modified_gmt',
        '$_post_content_filtered',
        '$_post_parent',
        '$_guide',
        '$_menu_order',
        '$_post_type',
        '$_post_mime_type',
        '$_comment_count'
      )
      ";
```

Logo abaixo, eu quero enviar o valor de ID gerado automaticamente na tabela  **wpne_posts** para a tabela wpne_postmeta, na coluna **post_id**, veja:

```
    mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM wpne_postmeta");
$sql2 = "

        INSERT INTO
      `wpne_postmeta`(`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
    VALUES
      (
        meta_id,
        'ID',
        '$meta_key_guest_name',
        '$meta_value_guest_name'
      ),
      (
        meta_id,
        'ID)',
        '$meta_key_timestamp',
        '$meta_value_timestamp'
      ),
      (
        meta_id,
        'ID',
        '$meta_key_timeslot',
        '$meta_value_timeslot'
      ),
      (
        meta_id,
        'ID',
        '$meta_key_cf_meta_value',
        '$meta_value_cf_meta_value'
      ),
        (
        meta_id,
        'ID',
        '$_appointment_title',
        ''
      ),
        (
        meta_id,
        'ID',
        '$_appointment_guest_surname',
        ''
      )

        ";

    mysqli_query($con, $sql1) or die("Erro SQL 1");
    mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die("Erro SQL 2");
```

Eu tentei fazer com **mysqli_insert_id()**, mas recebo valor 0. 
Gostaria de salvar o valor do ID da tabela wpne_posts em uma variável ou qualquer outra solução.

Acho que sou meio leigo, de toda forma agradeço ajuda.

Comment: você fez `mysqli_insert_id($con)` ?

Comment: Você precisa executar isso entre as duas queries. Precisa mudar a ordem das operações do seu código. E por que tem esses SELECT no meio?

Comment: Por que inverter? acho que já fritei o cérebro tentando isso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor forma de fazer isso é usando a função `mysqli_insert_id()`. Porém isso implica que a chave primária da sua tabela tenha a característica **AUTO_INCREMENT**, ou seja, a sua chave deve ter sido gerada pelo auto incrimento. Modifique o seu `INSERT` e simplesmente não informe o campo `ID`.

Vamos a um exemplo prático:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "meu_usuario", "minha_senha","meu_bd");

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Pessoas (PrimeiroNome, SegundoNome, Idade) 
    VALUES ('Pedro', 'Souza', 25)");

    $idGerado = mysqli_insert_id($con);

    // Imprimir o auto-generated ID
    echo "O novo ID do registro é: " . $idGerado; 

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Repare que no `INSERT` executado acima, preenchi os campos e os valores, mas não informei a coluna ID, pois isso é trabalho do **MySQL**, saber quem é a chave primária e uma vez que ela é AUTO_INCREMENT, atribuí-la. Após isso a função `mysqli_insert_id()` é capaz de capta-la.

Após isso posso usar esse meu ID captado, para realizar outros INSERTS:

```
<?php
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Profissoes (IDPessoa, Profissao) 
    VALUES (" . $idGerado . ", 'Analista de Sistemas')");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução foi inverter e usar mysqli_insert_id($con)
salvando em uma variével antes de executar a query da segunda tabela:

```
$ID = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

A forma nativa (sem funções PHP) de identificar o último ID gerado pelo **auto_increment** é a função:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Ela deve ser invocada logo a seguir a uma instrução INSERT.

**Nota:** *O ID que foi gerado é mantido no servidor por conexão. Significa que o ID gerado não afecta os ID's gerados por outras ligações/clientes.*

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Usando o seu exemplo:

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO `wpne_posts`(`ID`, `post_author`,`post_date`, ....)
                        VALUES (ID, '$_post_author','$_post_date', ....)";

//executa a instrução INSERT
mysqli_query($con, $sql1);

//obtem o último ID duma instrução INSERT
$lastID = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");

//insere na segunda tabela
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO  `wpne_postmeta`(`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
VALUES (meta_id, $lastID,'$meta_key_guest_name', '$meta_value_guest_name')";

//executa o script
mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
```